# NGINX and .NetCore application performance

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, nginx, .net-core

I have a .netCore 5 website hosted with NGINX  Linux Ubuntu

I need to select a new server and wonder where I can save money

My app is very small
My APP does NOT  HDDs nothing store in the file system

I notice that even I overwrite with the new version (new files) the application does not change until I restart the tread.

My focus is to save money from the HDD
And buy servers with old HDD

Question
How NGINX  works?

1. Load in the memory the app and serve from there?
2. You have the location of the files but create some cache and serve from there – WHICH means a Hard drive is important

In Short: Does NGINX   used the hard drive?

My app is using CDN for all files they are on 3rd part Azure Blobs and Amazon S3

I want to save on HDD  instead of SSD and nVME

Which HDDs to select to get the best performance?
Again my app server only web from 3rd party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much already have the answer. NGINX won't do disk writes or reads unless it needs to.

For your case, static files are hosted elsewhere, so obviously your NGINX has no need to interact with the disk for serving those.

The app is served by using NGINX as a reverse proxy. The communication between the NGINX and the app is usually done over a network socket (e.g. your app binds to a TCP port) or a UNIX socket. For neither of the two, the disk speed would matter.

You would probably better ask yourself if your app logic does any reads or writes to disk. And if the answer is no or "not much", then yes, a plain HDD would be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you Danila